# how to catch Json data error when value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This is a snipped of my code, this part of the code shows json data being presented in the html but if a value is undefined it just doesnt show anything. how would i catch this error to make so if a value is undefined it will say "N/A" instead of just breaking

```
  var $this=$(this),
                    movie = $this.data('movie');

                $('.active').removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');

                $("#movieInfo").html(`
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="${movie.info.image}" class="thumbnail" style="width:300px;height:400px">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
       <h4>${movie.title}</h4>
       <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Genre:</strong> ${movie.info.genres}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Year:</strong> ${movie.year}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Released date:</strong> ${movie.info.release_date}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rank:</strong> ${movie.info.rank}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rating:</strong> ${movie.info.rating}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Directors:</strong> ${movie.info.directors}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Running Time:</strong> ${movie.info.running_time_secs}</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Actors:</strong> ${movie.info.actors}</li>

       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="well">
       <h5>Plot</h5>
       ${movie.info.plot}
       <hr>
       <a href="https://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=${movie.title}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Rotten Tomatoes</a>
       <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Go Back To Search</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   `);
```

so for example if 'movie.info.rating' is not defined for one of the films i want it to say "N/A"

Comment: you could do `${movie.info.rating || 'N/A'}`

Answer (score 0):

If you destructure the data and provide default values:

`const {thing = 'N/A'} = movie`

If you want to do it inline:

`{$movie.whatever || 'N/A'}`